# Expose REST service with Biztalk

Tags: c#, biztalk

I'm trying to build Biztalk app that can expose REST services and accept JSON messages instead of SOAP XML.

What I did is : I have created couple of schemes and orchestrations and published the schemes as WCF service. Then I also created custom piplines to decode json to xml. 
However, this seems to work only with xml requests with `Content-Type:application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8` header.

If a change the content type to Content-Type: application/json it fails with

> Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json'
>   was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.

Been searching all over the net for the solution. And now i'm not sure if it can be achieved at all, does any one know?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: What adapter and what version of BizTalk you are using?

Comment: @OlegDeribas Biztalk 2013 and WCF-WSHttp adapter

Comment: AFAIK WCF-WSHttp adapter works only with SOAP messages. If you want JSON it is better to use WCF-WebHTTP. In BT 2013 you'd still need custom pipeline component to convert JSON to XML. And BT 2013R2 supports JSON natively.

Comment: @OlegDeribas thanks for the tip, it worked. Please post your answer so i can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF-WSHttp adapter works only with SOAP messages. If you want JSON it is better to use WCF-WebHTTP. In BT 2013 you'd still need custom pipeline component to convert JSON to XML. And BT 2013R2 supports JSON natively.